# Failed to start RAFT Orderer Service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

tls handshake failed with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer
I am trying to create the RAFT based orederer service but it is not working. The orderer nodes are start but do not communicate with them due to some tls handshake error. The node service is also failed to create channel as orderer is giving some tls handshake error.

I have checked the certificate paths and they are all correct.

Organizations:

```
 - &Orderer

    Name: Orderer
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/msp

- &Org1
    Name: CompanyOne
    ID: CompanyOneMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/companyone.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: 192.168.152.235
          Port: 7051

- &Org2
    Name: companytwo
    ID: companytwoMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/companytwo.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: 192.168.152.236
          Port: 7051
- &Org3
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    Name: CompanyThree
    ID: CompanyThreeMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/companythree.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: 192.168.152.237
          Port: 7051
```

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
        - *Org1
        - *Org2
        - *Org3
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft

```
Addresses:
    - 192.168.152.231:7050
    - 192.168.152.232:7050
    - 192.168.152.233:7050

# Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
BatchTimeout: 2s

# Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
BatchSize:

    # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
    MaxMessageCount: 10

    # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch.
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

    # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
    # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

EtcdRaft:

    Consenters:
        - Host: 192.168.152.231
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/companyone.orderer.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/companyone.orderer.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: 192.168.152.232
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/companytwo.orderer.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/companytwo.orderer.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: 192.168.152.233
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/companythree.orderer.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.com/orderers/companythree.orderer.com/tls/server.crt

    # Options to be specified for all the etcd/raft nodes. The values here
    # are the defaults for all new channels and can be modified on a
    # per-channel basis via configuration updates.
    Options:
        # TickInterval is the time interval between two Node.Tick invocations.
        TickInterval: 500ms

        # ElectionTick is the number of Node.Tick invocations that must pass
        # between elections. That is, if a follower does not receive any
        # message from the leader of current term before ElectionTick has
        # elapsed, it will become candidate and start an election.
        # ElectionTick must be greater than HeartbeatTick.
        ElectionTick: 10

        # HeartbeatTick is the number of Node.Tick invocations that must
        # pass between heartbeats. That is, a leader sends heartbeat
        # messages to maintain its leadership every HeartbeatTick ticks.
        HeartbeatTick: 1

        # MaxInflightBlocks limits the max number of in-flight append messages
        # during optimistic replication phase.
        MaxInflightBlocks: 5

        # SnapshotIntervalSize defines number of bytes per which a snapshot is taken
        SnapshotIntervalSize: 20 MB

# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
# the orderer side of the network
Organizations:
    - *Org1
    - *Org2
    - *Org3
```

Profiles:

```
OrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Orderer
    Consortiums:
        GeneralConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
ConsortiumChannel:
    Consortium: GeneralConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
            - *Org3
```

Comment: Specify your environment TLS variables such as ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_XXX

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, it sounds to me like you have not appropriately configured your orderers to utilize the TLS certificates referenced in your channel configuration.

Take a look at the orderer logs as they start.  You will most likely see a message a warning message like:

```
Could not find 
<pem encoded cert block>
among
<repeated PEM encoded cert blocks>
```

indicating that TLS has not been correctly configured for the local ordering process to match your genesis block.